# DevExpress 12.2.7 summary format string not work

Tags: winforms, devexpress, xtrareport

I usually use string.Format(arg, object)in `Before Print` of `XrTableCell` to format string as decimal dotted.
In the bottom of each page I have one Group Footer to `summary` the page.
But in the summary XrTableCell (`xrTableCell50`) I can't format my string, when debugging, it's value is not the printed value too!, and the printed is without the dots

Comment: It's worked, I stopped with the code, in the design window of XtraReport, select Summary-> Format string and set it to {0:n0}

Comment: Have you set Summary.Running property to Page?

Comment: No, I haven't, I just do like my comment above